# want sql query which give me name of the column which contain particular data

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have five columns which have a data type `int`. I have selected row on the basis of primary key, but now in this row I want to select particular column with name which has value less than some int value of the resulted column.

```
USE [MedicalLabDB]

GO

/****** Object: Table [dbo].[Advance_Sub_Tests] Script Date: 01/11/2012 15:33:11 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Advance_Sub_Tests]
  (
     [Advance_Sub_Test_ID]           [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
     [Sub_Test_ID]                   [INT] NULL,
     [L_Bound_M_LessThan_First_Age ] [FLOAT] NULL,
     [U_Bound_M_LessThan_First_Age ] [FLOAT] NULL,
     [L_Bound_M_LessThan_Second_Age] [FLOAT] NULL,
     [U_Bound_M_LessThan_Second_Age] [FLOAT] NULL,
     [L_Bound_M_LessThan_Third_Age]  [FLOAT] NULL,
     [U_Bound_M_LessThan_Third_Age]  [FLOAT] NULL,
     [L_Bound_M_LessThan_Fourth_Age] [FLOAT] NULL,
     [U_Bound_M_LessThan_Fourth_Age] [FLOAT] NULL,
     [L_Bound_M_LessThan_Fifth_Age]  [FLOAT] NULL,
     [U_Bound_M_LessThan_Fifth_Age]  [FLOAT] NULL,
     [L_Bound_F_LessThan_First_Age]  [FLOAT] NULL,
     [U_Bound_F_LessThan_First_Age]  [FLOAT] NULL,
     [L_Bound_F_LessThan_Second_Age] [FLOAT] NULL,
     [U_Bound_F_LessThan_Second_Age] [FLOAT] NULL,
     [L_Bound_F_LessThan_Third_Age]  [FLOAT] NULL,
     [U_Bound_F_LessThan_Third_Age]  [FLOAT] NULL,
     [L_Bound_F_LessThan_Fourth_Age] [FLOAT] NULL,
     [U_Bound_F_LessThan_Fourth_Age] [FLOAT] NULL,
     [L_Bound_F_LessThan_Fifth_Age]  [FLOAT] NULL,
     [U_Bound_F_LessThan_Fifth_Age]  [FLOAT] NULL,
     [First_Age]                     [INT] NULL,
     [Second_Age]                    [INT] NULL,
     [Third_Age]                     [INT] NULL,
     [Fourth_Age]                    [INT] NULL,
     [Fifth_Age]                     [INT] NULL,
     [Test_Active]                   [BIT] NULL,
     [Version]                       [TIMESTAMP] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Advance_Sub_Test_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
     [Advance_Sub_Test_ID] ASC )WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
  )
ON [PRIMARY]
```

i have that table i want to select the column name (which is among first age,second age,thirdage,fourth age,fifth age) which has the value let assume <20 (i selected a particular row already)

Comment: "particular column with name which has value less than some int value", what do you mean with this?

Comment: Sample data and expected output would be helpful to understand what you want.

Comment: Have you considered restructuring this to get rid of the apparent repeating groups? (i.e. moving all the `Age` stuff out to another table and represent it as 5 rows not across columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want a column name as a result.

Try this:

```
select top(1) Age.ColumnName
from Advance_Sub_Tests as AST
  cross apply (
               select 1, 'First_Age',  AST.First_Age  union all
               select 2, 'Second_Age', AST.Second_Age union all
               select 3, 'Third_Age',  AST.Third_Age  union all
               select 4, 'Fourth_Age', AST.Fourth_Age union all
               select 5, 'Fifth_Age',  AST.Fifth_Age
              ) as Age(Sortorder, ColumnName, ColumnValue)
where AST.Advance_Sub_Test_ID = 1 and 
      Age.ColumnValue < 20
order by Age.Sortorder
```

Comment: if i want to use only first column from the resulted value then what can i do

Comment: @user1023160 - Add a column to use in order by and do a `select top(1)`. Updated answer.